# Python: update parent in for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, parent

I would like to update my parent id correctly.

My existing list of dictionaries

```
id prj_id   parent
1  808348   1
2  808352   2
3  808356   3
4  808361   4
5  808365   0
6  808370   0
7  808370   6
8  808370   7
9  808370   8
```

Now I want to get it, that my parents get the number of the parent project

My Code:

```
index = 0
last_prj_id = ""

for row in result_gantt:
    current_prj_id = row['prj_id']
    parent = row['parent']
    parent = index

    if current_prj_id == last_prj_id:
        parent = last_id
    else:
        parent = index

    last_prj_id = row['prj_id']
    last_id = row['id']
```

Result from the Code:

```
id prj_id   parent
1  808348   0
2  808352   0
3  808356   0
4  808361   0
5  808365   0
6  808370   0
7  808370   6
8  808370   7
9  808370   8
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how I get it out that the entry with the **id 7** to **id 9** get the parent of the **id 6**

This is how the issue should look like.

```
id prj_id   parent
1  808348   0
2  808352   0
3  808356   0
4  808361   0
5  808365   0
6  808370   0
7  808370   6
8  808370   6
9  808370   6
```

I do not know how to continue. Would appreciate your help

Comment: A little more description of your problem would be appreciated. Your list of dictionaries doesn't look like a list or dictionary.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how I get it out that the entry with the id 7 to id 9 get the parent of the id 6

Comment: this looks like a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
result_gantt = [{"id":1,"prj_id":808348,"parent":1},{"id":2,"prj_id":808352,"parent":2},{"id":3,"prj_id":808356,"parent":3},{"id":4,"prj_id":808361,"parent":4},{"id":5,"prj_id":808365,"parent":0},{"id":6,"prj_id":808370,"parent":0},{"id":7,"prj_id":808370,"parent":6},{"id":8,"prj_id":808370,"parent":7},{"id":9,"prj_id":808370,"parent":8}]

index = 0
prev_index = 0 # To maintain the index in case of consecutive id's
last_prj_id = ""
check = False # Check for consecutive id's
for row in result_gantt:
    current_prj_id = row['prj_id']
    parent = row['parent']
    parent = index

    if current_prj_id == last_prj_id:
        if not check: # Will be true in case of consecutive id's
            prev_index = last_id
        parent = last_id
        check = True
    else:
        check = False
        parent = index

    last_prj_id = row['prj_id']
    last_id = row['id']
    row['parent'] = parent if not check else prev_index

for i in result_gantt:
    print i
```

Output:

```
{'prj_id': 808348, 'id': 1, 'parent': 0}
{'prj_id': 808352, 'id': 2, 'parent': 0}
{'prj_id': 808356, 'id': 3, 'parent': 0}
{'prj_id': 808361, 'id': 4, 'parent': 0}
{'prj_id': 808365, 'id': 5, 'parent': 0}
{'prj_id': 808370, 'id': 6, 'parent': 0}
{'prj_id': 808370, 'id': 7, 'parent': 6}
{'prj_id': 808370, 'id': 8, 'parent': 6}
{'prj_id': 808370, 'id': 9, 'parent': 6}
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I just could not come up with the solution. But your solution is very plausible. Thanks again

Comment: Happy to help @justintime